# How to connect to database using SQLite(3) after creating executable JAR?

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx, jar, executable-jar

**Context:**
I'm creating an application that lets a user connect to a database. This database is chosen by a FileChooser. If no database is selected, the application should connect to a sample database that comes with the program instead. The sample database is located inside src/files(/sample.db).

**Problem:**
The DriverManager.getConnection() method does not seem to work when I build the program as an executable JAR. It does however work in IntelliJ.

**Code:**

```
try {  
    System.out.println(selectedDB);  
    if (selectedDB == null) {  
        // TODO: make sure this works in JAR.  
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite::resource:files/sample.db");  
    } else {  
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + selectedDB.toString());  
    }  
} catch (SQLException ex) {  
    ex.printStackTrace();  
    System.out.println("If you see this message, the DatabaseManager failed to make a connection to the database.");  
    System.out.println("This is most likely due to a fault in the databasename");  
}
```

Should other code extracts be needed to answer this question, please ask.
Thanks in advance!

**Error:**
connection *remains* null after the above method is done, instead of a working connection.

**Pictures:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqGVR.jpg
(Not enough reputation to post image itsself, only recently started stackoverflowing.)
Edit: Becomes -> remains

Comment: "does not [..] work" => You have to describe the error!

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose My bad, added what happened vs what was expected.

Comment: I doubt that `connection` will be `null` after that piece of code is run. Maybe it throws an exception which you swallow, but then work with the variable `connection` ...

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Yes, most likely. The problem only arises when the program tries to use a function on this connection later. Would you know why the connection throws an exception when executing a JAR file, but not when testing in IntelliJ?

Comment: You have to tell us the exception (and the stack trace)!

Comment: how is this related to fx?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Added link to stacktrace pictures (and updated code to show more details).

Comment: Which condition line invokes this exception if or else ?

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine The if-condition, although the else-condition does it as well. But I haven't really tried to make that one work yet.

Comment: A stacktrace is text! Please post it as one in your question (not as a picture). Additionally, always show the line (in your own code) where the exception occurs.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Will remember that for next time. Also, the line where the exception occurs is not very relevant to my problem, it is just a sideeffect. The real problem is that the above declaration of connection seems to become invalid when you compile the program into an executable jar file.